# Place div containing an image with undefined size at bottom of another div

Tags: html, css

I have the following Problem: I have a slideshow using JScript wich changes the image every couple seconds...
The image sizes may vary and therefore I created a frame containing the Image-Frame in order to prevent the rest of the Page moving up and down:

```css
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.frame {
  height: 900px;
}
.slideshow-container img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div class="slideshow-container">
    <img href="exampleImage.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

The inner div has the size of the image, which is supposed to be like that, but now I want the inner div with the image to be at the bottom of the outer div while maintaining it's size.

Any ideas?

Comment: position: relative the outer and position:absolute and bottom:0 to the inner

Comment: @YehiaAwad that sticks the div to the bottom of my browser frame...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    .frame  {
        position: relative;
    }

    .slideshow-container {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }
```

Comment: If you could tell me how I center the slideshow div, then this gets accepted

Comment: add text-align: center to the .frame class

Comment: This doesn't work :c - I need to center it horizontally

Comment: Something like this possibly? http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_align_line-height